# С++. Конструктор копирования для класса содержащего поля абстрактного типа

Tags: c++, конструктор-копирования

Как правильно написать конструктор для класса В?

```
class А {
public:
    virtual А* clone() = 0;
    virtual ~А() {}
};

class B {
public:
    B(const B& obj);
    ~B();

private:

    A* b;
    A* c;
    std::string* s;
};   

 B::~B() {
    delete b;
    delete c;
    delete s;
}
```

Вот так?

```
B::B(const B &obj) {
    s = new std::string(*obj.s);
}
```

Comment: Да. А так, что вы имеете в виду под *полями абстрактного типа*? Абстрактный класс отличается от обычного только неполностью заполненной таблицей виртуальных функций. Никаких различий больше нет.

Comment: не пишите так `std::string* s;` если только Вы точно не понимаете, что Вы хотите сделать. Пишите просто строку (то есть, удалите звездочку). Это упростит код.

Comment: @Arhad А что вы думаете по поводу ответа AnT ниже?

Comment: **В первом абзаце** Ant говорит о том, что даже если `A` – абстрактный класс (из-за чего нельзя объявлять переменные типа этого класса), указатели на него всё равно не являются абстрактным типом (то есть их можно создавать и разыменовывать без ограничений). **Во втором абзаце** он говорит, что клонирование объектов `b` и `c` при копировании `B` необходимо только в том случае, если `B` является полноправным владельцем этих объектов, то есть уничтожает их в своём деструкторе. В противном случае достаточно простого копирования указателей на исходные объекты.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во-первых, в вашем классе `B` нет никаких "полей абстрактного типа". Абстрактный тип в вашем примере - `A`. В классе `B` нет полей типа `A`. Есть лишь поля типа `A *`, но `A *` - не абстрактный тип.

Во-вторых, как правильно написать копирование для класса `B` зависит от того, что вы хотели выразить этим `A *` - агрегацию или простую неагрегирующую ссылку. Копирование объектов `A` нужно только в первом случае. И как оно будет выполняться зависит от того, как реализована семантика копирования для `A`. У вас, я вижу, специально заведен метод `clone` в `A`. Я, разумеется, не телепат и не знаю, для чего предназначен этот загадочный метод `clone`, но его название и описание соответствует существующей идиоме (однако, по идее, он должен быть `const`). Если это так, то в чем вопрос - копируйте на здоровье

```
B::B(const B &obj) : 
   b(obj.b->clone()),
   c(obj.c->clone()), 
   s(new std::string(*obj.s))
  {}
```

Тут, разумеется, есть над чем подумать в области защиты от потенциально выбрасываемых исключений. И, в том числе по этой причине, совершенно не ясно, почему объект типа `std::string` вдруг агрегирован через *указатель* (?). Но общая идея - вот она.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Под "поля абстрактного типа" я подразумевал A* b и A*c. Назвал их так, потому что класс А - абстрактный, а b и c типа А.